# Can't use tilde (~) for sed -i backup character on OSX: "sed: rename(): Not a directory"

Tags: bash, macos, sed, tilde-expansion

On my OSX machine, I can't use ~ as the backup character for in-place sed. Any other character is fine. The error I get is... cryptic: `rename(): Not a directory`.

Example:

```
$ echo foo > bar
$ sed -i ~ -e s/foo/hello/ bar
sed: rename(): Not a directory
$ ls -1
bar
$ cat bar
foo
$ sed -i _ -e s/foo/hello/ bar
$ ls -1
bar
bar_
$ cat bar
hello
$ cat bar_
foo
```

Comment: not actually about sed, it turns out, but this is a common command to have a stand-alone tilde with and the error message doesn't explain what's going on. took me a month to figure this out, had to break out dtruss and felt quite dumb in the end :P hope it helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash automatically expands a stand-alone tilde (`~`) into $HOME:

```
$ echo ~
/Users/hraban
```

Therefore, `sed -i ~` becomes `sed -i /home/you`, which leads sed to try to
rename `bar` to `bar/home/you`---a directory that doesn't exist. To fix this,
escape the tilde in bash:

```
$ sed -i \~ -e s/foo/hello/ bar
$ cat bar
hello
```